# Не получается скачать pullrequest/ветку в свой проект через композер

Tags: php, git, composer

Пробую скачать ветку пулреквест проекта. В пустую папку. Т.е. все с нуля.

Для примера взял проект https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle

Взял один из пулреквестов: https://github.com/gmponos/guzzle/tree/final-annotation

Мой composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "root/site",
    "require": {
        "guzzle/guzzle": "dev-final-annotation"
    },
    "repositories": [
       {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/gmponos/guzzle"
       }
    ]
}
```

Делаю `composer update`

Получаю ошибку:

```
Problem 1
    - The requested package guzzle/guzzle dev-final-annotation exists as guzzle/guzzle[dev-mark-abandoned, dev-master, 3.9.x-dev, v1.0.3, v1.0.4, v2.0.0, v2.0.1, v2.0.2, v2.0.3, v2.0.4, v2.0.5, v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.3.2, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.5.0, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.2, v2.8.3, v2.8.4, v2.8.5, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6, v3.0.7, v3.1.0, v3.1.1, v3.1.2, v3.2.0, v3.3.0, v3.3.1, v3.4.0, v3.4.1, v3.4.2, v3.4.3, v3.5.0, v3.6.0, v3.7.0, v3.7.1, v3.7.2, v3.7.3, v3.7.4, v3.8.0, v3.8.1, v3.9.0, v3.9.1, v3.9.2, v3.9.3] but these are rejected by your constraint.
```

Как я понимаю, поиск идет без учета репозитория пулреквеста.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: [Нельзя просто так взять](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55294339/composer-require-a-specific-pull-request) и запросить pull request, но можно это сделать с веткой.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov я сам делал форк, делал косметические изменения в новой ветке, заливал в свой гитаккаунт. Пулреквест не оформлял. Результат - тот же самый.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov попробовал другие ветки из этого репозитория, которые не являются пулреквестами - та же ошибка. П.С. Я и первый раз не сам пулреквест забирал - а ветку.

Comment: Ваша ветка называется final-annotation, без dev-

Comment: @DanielProtopopov dev- это спец обозначение для веток разработки https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs  без этой приставки комозер даже запускаться отказывается

Comment: в хранилище https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle нет ни ветки, ни метки с именем "final-annotation". вот об этом в ошибке, собственно, и написано.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin так мне нужно ветку эту скачать не с guzzle/guzzle а с форка gmponos/guzzle. В этом и суть. А почему кастомный репозиторий не учитывается - не могу понять.

Comment: Попробуйте для начала удалить существующий модуль guzzle (если он есть) из папки вендоров, затем поменять местами require и repositories (repositories первым), а потом если это всё не поможет использовать пример [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13325158/contributing-to-open-source-bundles-from-vendor-directory/27970559#27970559). Можете добавить флаг вербозности для composer update чтобы видеть как именно происходит процесс.

Comment: *так мне нужно ветку эту скачать не с guzzle/guzzle а с форка gmponos/guzzle* — но вы-то указываете скачивать ветку "final-annotation" именно из хранилища `https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle`. вот это ваше указание: `"require": { "guzzle/guzzle": "dev-final-annotation" }`. что указываете — то и получаете (ошибку).

Comment: @DanielProtopopov я удалял, ставил через composer require - эффект тотже. Через package - не пробовал.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin в этом и есть вся суть этого метода - в require указывается главный пакет, а в репозиториях - форк.  Вот пример из документации: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Спасибо за уделенное время, ошибку нашел, накасячил в названиях пакетов.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin в общем этот способ работает) с названиями пакетов накасячил)

Answer (score 2):

Причина найдена - был взят abandoned пакет.  А пул реквест брался из актуального. Схожие названия на packagist и github.

Abandoned на packagist **guzzle/guzzle** , на github guzzle/guzzle3

Актульный на packagist guzzlehttp/guzzle, на github **guzzle/guzzle**

Т.е. верный и рабочий composer.json

```
{
    "name": "root/site",
    "require": {
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "dev-final-annotation"
    },
    "repositories": [
       {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/gmponos/guzzle"
       }
    ]
}
```